# Implementar web service php

Tags: php, java, webservice, soap

Buen día estoy teniendo problema para consumir un servicie realizado en java.
Tengo [este ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Nfc9lYgxNiVD202xzIVfWVMM06yJ3sI)  que esta hecho en java y funciona correctamente pero cuando lo intento hacer en php no funciona.

Aqui mi código:

```html
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
$wsdl = 'https://dpfactura.com.co/wsFact_e/InterSoap?wsdl';  // @see http://developer.yousign.fr/
$headerbody = array(
  'username' => 'FHEMATOLOGICA',
  'password' => 'PASSWORD',
  'token'  => 'TOKEN'
);
$header = new SOAPHeader($wsdl, 'InterSoap', $headerbody);        
        
// set the Headers of Soap Client.
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
$eBfelEncabezadofacturas = array(
  'tipodocumento ' => "1",
  'prefijo' => "PRUE",
  'consecutivo' => 984130000,
  'echafacturacion'=>"2018-08-04 10:00:00",
  'moneda'=>"COP",
  'totalimportebruto'=>190000.00,
  'totalbaseimponible'=>1000000.00,
  'totalfactura'=>1190000.00,
  'tiponota'=>"2",
  'tokenempresa'=>'55ef06e54e7faee0614f26ff86a8933aee16c72b'
);
$respuesta = $client->__soapCall("enviarFactura", $eBfelEncabezadofacturas);
?>
```

Comment: Saludos, pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: Todavía necesitas el código?

Comment: La verdad muchísimo, me esto volviendo loco  tratando de conectarme a ese web service te agradecería cualquier ayuda :)

Comment: La verdad entiendo el sentimiento, utilizando métodos tradicionales como el nativo SOAP o la class Nusoap, yo en lo personal no logre conseguirlo, para poder utilizar ese WS tuve que crear una clase nueva, a lo cual tuve éxito, en estos momentos estoy terminando de crear la clase para que sea mas sencilla su utilización si estas interesando yo voy a poner en venta el código por $730USD por Paypal ó $2millones si estas en Colombia.